# How to import SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment into an Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to use Android's `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment` in a project, but for some reason Android Studio complains that `Can not resolve symbol SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment`. Am I missing something in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

I checked the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) but there was mention of which library is required to use this fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment` requires ***Google Play Services 8.4*** and you are using Google Play Services 7.5.0

Use : 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

or

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`

Reference : [New AutoComplete Widget](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2015/12/autocomplete-widget-and-updated-place.html).

Here is [Sample Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places) for implementing the same.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather from a quick look at the documentation, you might be missing the Android Support Library reference in your project. Go to tools->Android->SDK Manager and under extras check if you have the **Android Support Library** installed, if not install it. Also, add a reference to it in your gradle file like this `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'`.

Comment: I just now noticed, but you seem to be missing the actual google services library. I managed to get ```SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment``` working with the following gradle dependencies```dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}```And
 ```import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment;```